# Add a class to the register, forgot password and connection link in the login page - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a class to the links at the bottom of the login page in Wordpress.

Actually, the page display the links like this :

```
<p id="nav">
   <a href="http://localhost:8888/testing/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>
   <a href="http://localhost:8888/testing/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Récupération de mot de passe">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
```

And I would like to add a class to those links :

```
<p id="nav">
   <a class="my-new-class" href="http://localhost:8888/testing/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>
   <a class="my-new-class" href="http://localhost:8888/testing/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Récupération de mot de passe">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
```

I tryied to add the class with jQuery but adding the script in the header.php doesn’t seems to affect the login page.

The best solution on my mind would be to be able to use a function in the functions.php to rewritte and return the link in the login.php.

Is there a way to do it without touching at the Wordpress core ?

Thank in advance !

Comment: this is a wordpress question not a php, jquery or html question

Answer (score 1):

There's only one hook that works for you:

`add_filter('register', function ($reg_link) {
    $result = str_replace('<a','<a class="new-class"', $reg_link);
   return $result;
});`

There is no hook for the second link, besides changing the *href, title, text*.

Your best bet is to go in the *wp-login.php* and hack away. After all it's a simple modification.